# sed replace '\\\' with newline Linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have multiple files with the following text:

```
20~02~19~05-01-52
2249\\\2249\\\2249\\\2249\\\2249\\\2249\\\2248\\\
```

I'd like to use sed or another Linux command to replace `\\\` with a newline.

Answer (score 13):

`sed 's|\\\\\\|\n|g' filename` does it, if you're using GNU `sed`.

If you want POSIX `sed`, then this should work (quite a lot of escaping!):

```
sed 's|\\\\\\|\
|g' filename
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd use Perl here since it has more advanced regexes that can easily support repetition. So, something like this:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\{3}/\n/g' file 
20~02~19~05-01-52
2249
2249
2249
2249
2249
2249
2248
```

The `-pe` means "print each input line after applying the script given by -e to it". The script itself simply replaces every occurrence of exactly 3 `\` with a newline. We need `\\` instead of `\` because the `\` needs to be escaped.

If your `sed` supports it (GNU sed does) you can use the same approach:

```
$ sed -E 's/\\{3}/\n/g' file 
20~02~19~05-01-52
2249
2249
2249
2249
2249
2249
2248
```

Comment: You can use `\\\{3\}` in standard BRE in `sed` as well. Actually, the `\{x,y\}` BRE operator is more portable than the `{x,y}` ERE operator.

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\{3}/, RS)}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

- `zsh`

```
printf '%s\n' ${(s:\\\:)"$(<FILE)"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed: `sed -n 's/\\\\\\/\n/g; p' filename.txt`.

It is important to have the 'p' after the semicolon, otherwise it would not print the first line where no substitution takes place. 6 backslashes because 3 backslashes used as escape characters for the 3 backslashes you have. 'g' for global. '-n' to avoid automatic printing.

Comment: I don't understand the bit about `p` and the first line. If I do the command without `-n` and without `p`, the output is the same, including the first line, at least with GNU's `sed`. Automatic printing does not depend on whether substitutions were made on a line.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! Yes, in this particular case, it works without the `-n` and `p` options. But usually I work with more complicated problems when using sed and automatic printing only gets in the way. It's normally easier when I always suppress automatic printing and print only when I want to, rather than having to think if this particular problem requires automatic suppression of printing.

Comment: For example. for this very same problem, if I want to instead print only where substitutions were made, then I would have my `p` command come in without the semicolon in between, like this: `sed -n 's/\\\\\\/\n/gp' filename.txt`. Or normally I don't want to print a certain range of files, and perform substitutions on the included lines in a file. So in almost all my use cases, I would need to suppress automatic printing, so I developed the habit. Otherwise you're right, don't need it in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach, assuming that the file has no other patterns like this, using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's;([0-9]{4}).{3};\1\n;g' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code that receives the Serial data and used the following to
generate linefeeds.
Thank you so much for the posts .  This will keep me studying for a while.

```
sed  -i 's/\\n/\n/g' *.txt
```